# Base64 encoder truncates returned Sting

Tags: string, base64, truncated

I’m displaying an image file in a HTML img tag using a data src URL that contains the image data in 64 byte in encoded format.

When I get the string from the encoded bytes, its terminated to a handfull of characters from what should be around 100k. I have a roll your own encoding routine that I lifted from somewhere and it works fine, albeit slow.

The file comes from a post of a multipart encoded form. I use Apache Commons' FileItem to parse the posted fields. The file contents are defined as a String there but it contains binary data. If I use my own encoder it works fine on the same data. I also use the same String to upload the file to AWS S3 and it works fine there. I tried bypassing the string thing and if I pass the file's InputStream to Base64.encode() I get the same error. Inspection of the returned encoded string shows its severely truncated.

Below `file` is a `String` variable that contains the image.  I’ve also tried passing an input stream to encode and get the same results.  I’ve tried `encode().toString()` and `encodeToString()`.   Also tried `new String(bytes, “UTF-8”)`.

I don't understand why `Base64.encodeToString` is truncating the returned ASCII string.  Any help would be appreciated.

Using Java and JSP.

```
String thumbUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(file.getBytes());

<img style="width:200px;" src="<%= thumbUrl %>" />
```

Update: code and output to demonstrate the problem.

```
byte[] temp = fileParam.value.getBytes();
System.out.println("input len: " + temp.length);
                
temp = Base64.getEncoder().encode(temp);
System.out.println("enc len: " + temp.length);

String z = new String(temp);
System.out.println("z string len: " + z.length());

System.out.println("enc string len: " + temp.toString().length());
                
String myEncString = NetHelper.encodeBase64(fileParam.value);
System.out.println("my encoder string len: " + myEncString.length());


Output:

input len: 3493
enc len: 4660
z string len: 4660  <<< GOOD string length.  Doesn't render
enc string len: 10  <<< BAD string returned
my encoder string len: 4660
```

Comment: Is it "truncating" by just a character or two?  The most common issue I see with Base64 encoding is with the padding characters at the end.  Some code/systems add the padding characters and some don't, some need the padding characters and some don't.  I'd check into that first.

Comment: No, it truncates a lot.  I added some code to show the problem and how my own encoder works fine.

Comment: Instead of toString() which truncates this almost works. 

String z = new String(temp);

Answer (score 0):

Glez,

The problem seems to be not with bytes encoding.

You mentioned that

> Below `file` is a `String` variable that contains the image.

Have you checked you loaded the file correctly?

Typically, one does not end up with `String` content when loading binary files in Java.
How do you load it? Have you checked the length of this string?

Comment: Agree and yes I have checked it.  I added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that new String(bytes) returns the correct length string.  I get a complete string back but it doesn't render properly so there's something else going on.  Perhaps there's a bug in Base64.toString() that truncates the returned string.